# Syntax of assigning a delegate variable in C#

Tags: c#

I looked over multiple questions here about delegates and I thought I had the correct Syntax but Visual 2012 is throwing an error:  myMethod Does Not exist in the current context.

```
class Class1
{
    public delegate void DoSomething(List<dynamic> input);

    List<dynamic> myData = new List<dynamic>();
    Delegate myMethod;

    public void AssignData(List<dynamic> input)
    {
        myData.Clear();
        myData.AddRange(input);
    }

    public void AssignFunction(DoSomething method)
    {
        myMethod = method;
    }

    public void CheckDel()
    {
        myMethod(myData);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the calling code which seems to work ok:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<dynamic> test = new List<dynamic>();
        test.Add(1);
        test.Add(2);
        test.Add(3);

        myClass.AssignData(test);
        myClass.AssignFunction(callBack);
        myClass.CheckDel();
    }
    public void callBack(List<dynamic> input)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(input[0].ToString());
    }
```

Everyting seems fine except CheckDel function returns the above error.  I'd like to be able to assign the Method anytime using AssignFunction.  Then Class1 can call that method using CheckDel method.

Comment: Why `Delegate myMethod;` and not `DoSomething myMethod;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your delegate is declared as a plain-old `Delegate` object, you must invoke it by calling the DynamicInvoke method.

`myMethod.DynamicInvoke(myData);`

For performance reasons it is better to declare your delegate as the specific type you want.  i.e. instead of `Delegate myMethod;`, you know it is a `DoSomething`, so use `DoSomething myMethod;`

Think of it as the analog of declaring

`object myObject;` vs `Class1 myObject;` -- you would need to cast the first one to `Class1` in order to invoke any `Class1` methods on it.

Indeed, you can cast `myMethod` to type `DoSomething` and it will work as expected:
`((DoSomething)myMethod)(myData);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. (and Cameron as well).  I migrating from just vanilla C to C# and still getting use to objects.   Your explanation made perfect sense.

Comment: Sure.  Also you should look into generics instead of dynamic.  It will give you strong typing while still letting you reuse your code.  It's similar to C++ templates.